# What arguments to give method names in a dict in __init__?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, dictionary, arguments

I'm working on Exercise 43 in Learn Python the Hard Way, trying to fill out the author's skeleton OOP code to make a working "adventure" type game.  I've never done any kind of OOP before the last few exercises in this text, so it's been hard going.

I'm using the `__init__` in a class to create the dictionary that provides "case" function (so it'll be available to all methods in the class) by storing calls referenced by keys (classic "make you own case statement" for Python), but the methods require arguments (to keep track of rooms already seen, carry inventory, etc.) -- and when I include variables for the arguments I invariably get an error that "[name] referenced before assignment" or similar.  If I provide blank or constant/literal arguments, I don't get that error, but obviously my calls later won't work correctly if the arguments aren't variables.

If I move the dict def into the primary method in the Engine class, everything seems fine, but then I'd have to define the whole dict again in each method in the class, right?  Here's the class I'm working on, with the dictionary in the primary method instead of the `__init__` -- how can I put this dictionary into `__init__` and have it work?

```
class Engine (object):

  def __init__(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map

  def drop_item(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def goto(self, c_list, inv, log):
    print c_list
    pass

  def take_item(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def inventory(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def show_items(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def set_bomb(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def talk_to(self, c_list, inv, log):
    pass

  def play(self):
    next_move = []
    stuff = []
    seen = []

    self.act = {
      'drop'        :self.drop_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'enter'       :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'get'         :self.take_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'go'          :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'inventory'   :self.inventory(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'leave'       :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'look'        :self.show_items(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'run'         :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'start'       :self.set_bomb(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'take'        :self.take_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'tell'        :self.talk_to(next_move, stuff, seen),
    }

    self.obj = {
      'armory'  :'',
      'blaster' :'',
      'bomb'    :'',
      'bridge'  :'',
      'cabin'   :'',
      'corridor':'',
      'gangway' :'',
      'gothon'  :'',
      'keypad'  :'',
      'pod'     :'',
      }

    self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    entry = UserEntry()

    done = False
    dead = False

    while not done:  
      next_move = entry.get_input()
      entry.obj [next_move (0)] (next_move)`
```

I'm trying to get something more like this:

```
  def __init__(self):
    self.scene_map = scene_map
    self.act = {
      'drop'        :self.drop_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'enter'       :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'get'         :self.take_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'go'          :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'inventory'   :self.inventory(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'leave'       :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'look'        :self.show_items(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'run'         :self.goto(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'start'       :self.set_bomb(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'take'        :self.take_item(next_move, stuff, seen),
      'tell'        :self.talk_to(next_move, stuff, seen),
    }

    self.obj = {
      'armory'  :'',
      'blaster' :'',
      'bomb'    :'',
      'bridge'  :'',
      'cabin'   :'',
      'corridor':'',
      'gangway' :'',
      'gothon'  :'',
      'keypad'  :'',
      'pod'     :'',
      }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: How do you hope to *use* `self.act` and `self.obj`?  What are they supposed to do?

Comment: At present, these are the lists of valid command words for the player to use, with the added effect that using the command words as keys in `self.act` lets me run the method that performs that function -- so if the player types in "get blaster", I'll run `self.take_item` and the arguments will tell `take_item` to check if there's a blaster in reach, and if so, add it to the player's inventory.

Comment: In your code example, you should include what you plan to do with `self.act` and `self.obj`, that is, code that uses them (even if it doesn't yet work).  It's not clear where you expect `next_move` and `stuff` and `seen` to come from.

Comment: I was trying to avoid TL;DR effect from pasting in hundreds of lines.  This isn't something that I can pare down to a minimum reproducer and still avoid questions like yours.  Short version: `next_move` is the parsed/trimmed command line entered by the user (should be just a verb and noun, like "start bomb"); `stuff` is the inventory list, and `seen` is the list of visited locations (to allow giving a long description on first seeing or explicit "look" command, and a shorter one on revisit -- as in original "Adventure" or "Colossal Cave").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were saving the results of calls to the methods in your dict. You probably want something like this in `__init__()`, to save references to the methods:

```
self.act = {
  'drop'        :self.drop_item,
  'enter'       :self.goto,
  'get'         :self.take_item,
  'go'          :self.goto,
  'inventory'   :self.inventory,
  'leave'       :self.goto,
  'look'        :self.show_items,
  'run'         :self.goto,
  'start'       :self.set_bomb,
  'take'        :self.take_item,
  'tell'        :self.talk_to,
}
```

I.e. refer to the methods without passing them the arguments. And then run the method to perform the action in `play()` by doing the actual calls:

```
self.act["the action"](next_move, stuff, seen)
```

Comment: And two minutes ago, I found that same information in another question I failed to find before posting mine.  Hard to get a good search in a few million questions...

Comment: Following up to say that this worked perfectly (once I killed another bug unrelated to the dictionaries) -- I went from error message to getting the correct method to run with the correct arguments in about ten minutes (and then fell into bed, hence the slow follow-up).